# Multiprocessing, return the function's value

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
def fun(a,b):
    return (a,b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(10): # I want to use 10 CPUs

        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun,args=(a,b,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Basically, I want to execute the function fun on 10 processors, so I get 10 results, but I want to store the returning values in two different arrays, so I get something like this in the end

```
x = [a,a,a,...,a]
y = [b,b,b,...,b]
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks at the `Pool()`. To open 10 processes, you can do `with multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 10) as p: p.map(function, input)`.

Comment: what are your source `a` and `b`? Constants? Values in two separate lists? Pairs of values (tuples) in one list?

Comment: a and b are floating values, like 0.5, or 0.7

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bad solution (because confusing and hard to read), but since your source is just two constants, it works. Except, it returns tuples, not lists:

```
import multiprocessing
import itertools

a=0.5
b=0.7
PROCS=10

def fun(a,b):
    return (a,b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=PROCS) as pool:
        result_a, result_b = zip(*pool.starmap(fun, zip(itertools.repeat(a,PROCS),itertools.repeat(b,PROCS))))
```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.13 and this does not work, I have the following error : 'pool' object has no attribute 'starmap'

Comment: Ah, this one was made in Python 3.5